# TypeError: loginScreen.visibleOfWelcome is not a function

Tags: javascript, export, detox, module-export

I want to access method defined in the javascript class. While running the code, I am getting error as

> TypeError: loginScreen.visibleOfWelcome is not a function

This is my code : 
firstPage.CCC.js

```
module.exports = class LoginScreen {

    get welcome() {
      return element(by.id("welcome"));
    }


    visibleOfWelcome() {
       expect(this.welcome).toBeVisible();
    }

  }
```

firstTest.specs.js

```
var loginScreen = require("./firstPage.CCC.js");

describe('Example', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await device.reloadReactNative();
  });

    it('should have welcome screen', async () => {
      await loginScreen.visibleOfWelcome();
    });
  })
```

If I write `await loginScreen.visibleOfWelcome();` then I get an error as

> TypeError: loginScreen.visibleOfWelcome is not a function

if write `await loginScreen.visibleOfWelcome;` then my code works file.

Any idea why ? I want to call as `await loginScreen.visibleOfWelcome();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try below solution:**

```
export class LoginScreen {

    get welcome() {
      return element(by.id("welcome"));
    }


    visibleOfWelcome() {
       expect(this.welcome).toBeVisible();
    }

  }
```

**Now here you can do this:**

```
var LoginScreen = require("./firstPage.CCC");
var loginScreen= new LoginScreen();

describe('Example', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await device.reloadReactNative();
  });

    it('should have welcome screen', async () => {
      await loginScreen.visibleOfWelcome();
    });
  })
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks, It is working now.. I did not add `var loginScreen= new LoginScreen();` after adding this line, it is works. Thanks, Shubham.

Comment: Does this line work: ```expect(this.welcome).toBeVisible();```? I thought `this.welcome` would be a function here, can `expect` work with functions or does it need an `element`?

Comment: @Daryn Bit of a late response, but `this.welcome` works because it is a "getter", in JavaScript when you access a property, it calls the getter function automatically. More info here: https://mdn.io/getter

Answer (score 2):

You have not instantiated the class `LoginScreen` so you can not access it's none static members like `visibleOfWelcome`. You have to create an instance of the class before exporting or after importing to be able to access it's members (Pretty much why it's OOP).

```
module.exports = new LoginScreen();

// Or

var LoginScreen = require("./firstPage.CCC.js");
var loginScreen = new LoginScreen();
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the need for creating the object also.